# How to delete values from array by using mask?

Tags: python, arrays

Subj. For example:

```
array = ['value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4', ...(here is many values like value5, value6, value7, value49 etc.)..., 'value50' 'something', 'something2']
```

I should delete value* from this array. How can I do this?

Comment: What do you mean by `value*` ? please post a *real* example with expected output, what have you tried and where did you get stuck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using list comprehension, filter out values starts with `value`:

```
>>> array = ['value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4', 'value50', 'something', 'something2']
>>> array = [x for x in array if not x.startswith('value')]  # NOTE: used `not`
>>> array
['something', 'something2']
```

Answer (score 0):

making simple things complex here is my code :)

```
from itertools import ifilterfalse
ifilterfalse(lambda x:x.startswith('value'),array)
```

**note if there are integer values in list you will get
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'startswith'**

so to handle integer also in your list 'array' we will use this simple loop:

```
res = []
for ele in array:
if type(ele) is int:
    res.append(ele)
elif not ele.startswith('value'):
    res.append(ele)
```